# Get Google Assistant Action to respond to "Quit" or "Cancel"

Tags: actions-on-google, dialogflow-es

I've tried to follow the [documentation about App Exit handling](https://developers.google.com/actions/assistant/app-exits), but it doesn't seem to be working correctly. (See the screen shot of my Intent below).

When I do it this way, it seems to resort to my Default Fallback Intent, although it does indicate that the `resolvedQuery` is `actions_intent_CANCEL`, which should be correct. (See the JSON body below.)

Am I doing something wrong, or is the documentation wrong?

Intent trying to handle it:

[image]

JSON Body:

```
{
    "originalRequest": {
        "source": "google",
        "version": "2",
        "data": {
            "isInSandbox": true,
            "surface": {
                "capabilities": [
                    {
                        "name": "actions.capability.AUDIO_OUTPUT"
                    },
                    {
                        "name": "actions.capability.SCREEN_OUTPUT"
                    }
                ]
            },
            "inputs": [
                {
                    "rawInputs": [
                        {}
                    ],
                    "intent": "actions.intent.CANCEL"
                }
            ],
            "user": {
                "locale": "en-US",
                "userId": "AETml1QP6omTPEXBfrOBdvNlwHxY"
            },
            "conversation": {
                "conversationId": "1509314271837",
                "type": "ACTIVE",
                "conversationToken": "[]"
            },
            "availableSurfaces": [
                {
                    "capabilities": [
                        {
                            "name": "actions.capability.AUDIO_OUTPUT"
                        },
                        {
                            "name": "actions.capability.SCREEN_OUTPUT"
                        }
                    ]
                }
            ]
        }
    },
    "id": "bbd363aa-f555-4543-a748-294751194fa9",
    "timestamp": "2017-10-29T21:58:00.691Z",
    "lang": "en-us",
    "result": {
        "source": "agent",
        "resolvedQuery": "actions_intent_CANCEL",
        "speech": "",
        "action": "input.unknown",
        "actionIncomplete": false,
        "parameters": {},
        "contexts": [
            {
                "name": "actions_intent_cancel",
                "parameters": {},
                "lifespan": 0
            },
            {
                "name": "actions_capability_screen_output",
                "parameters": {},
                "lifespan": 0
            },
            {
                "name": "actions_capability_audio_output",
                "parameters": {},
                "lifespan": 0
            }
        ],
        "metadata": {
            "intentId": "25f6e14b-a92c-479b-8943-76c4b6914579",
            "webhookUsed": "true",
            "webhookForSlotFillingUsed": "false",
            "nluResponseTime": 2,
            "intentName": "Default Fallback Intent"
        },
        "fulfillment": {
            "speech": "I'm sorry. I didn't quite grasp what you just said.",
            "messages": [
                {
                    "type": 0,
                    "id": "535c3b80-f13d-4b61-8c1d-bb58fa3f5e44",
                    "speech": "I'm a bit confused by that last part."
                }
            ]
        },
        "score": 1
    },
    "status": {
        "code": 200,
        "errorType": "success"
    },
    "sessionId": "1509314271837"
}
```

Comment: Are you making sure you do:
In the left navigation, click Integrations
Choose Google Assistant and click UPDATE DRAFT, then TEST to make sure the changes are reflected in your app.
?

Comment: Multiple times. This morning, disabling the fallback intent, it triggers the intent above. No idea what I did differently this morning. *rub temples*

Comment: I found that I had to update the console too.
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZvZDokjhUIY

Comment: What if I want to redirect the user to the default welcome intent when he says "cancel" or "exit"

Comment: @JayPatel - That sounds like a different question, and I would suggest you ask it as a new StackOverflow question.

Comment: Okay @Prisoner, Thanks I've posted it
 https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52040808/redirect-user-to-the-default-welcome-intent-when-he-says-cancel-or-exit

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In addition to the steps in the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/actions/assistant/app-exits), I found that I had to tell the simulator to update to the most recent version!

Here is my video outlining the steps I took.
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZvZDokjhUIY

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Although this isn't what the documentation suggests, I've found a workaround that seems to be correct.

Since there doesn't seem to be any spoken input registered, it looks like it would make sense for a Fallback Intent. Since Fallback Intents other than the default one require a Context, and not just an Event, and it looks like the `actions_intent_cancel` context is created, it seems reasonable to use it.

A Fallback Intent for this might look something like this:

[image]