# Redirect user to the Default Welcome Intent when he says "cancel" or "exit"

Tags: dialogflow-es, actions-on-google

I'm developing a Dialogflow application for Google Assitant. In that, if I say "Cancel" it directly calls the `exit_conversation` intent where I've specified `actions_intent_CANCEL` event. So it displays the output specified in that intent and bot exit the conversation.

Instead of exiting the Bot I need to open Default Welcome Intent. Is there any way to do that?

**P.S.** I'm using Python fulfillment as a backend for this bot.

Answer (score 5):

In short - no, you can't do that.

You're essentially asking that, when the user tries to quit, you don't want to let them quit. From Google's and your users' point of view - that is a pretty unacceptable option.

The CANCEL event handler is fairly limited with what it can do - Google will terminate the conversation, even if you don't specify that the microphone should be closed, but you're given the opportunity to say a final message and offer a link to elsewhere.

Comment: is there a way to call welcome intent without saying anything

Comment: @Sana - this sounds like an unrelated question. Go ahead and post a new question on StackOverflow. Make sure you've provided background information that explains exactly what you're trying to do, with as much information or examples as you can. See [How do I Ask a Good Question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)